# How can I avoid overflow of content when the website is opened in different devices of different sizes?

Tags: css

I am developing a website, and added some text in circular div. Its fine in my laptop. When I open in my phone (for checking), it overflows automatically. What can be the reason? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Stand on the shoulders of giants, such as Bootstrap.

Comment: Please add some code sample or a minimum-working example on JSFiddle or CodePen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very broad, so answer is also just a generic recommendation. First, in CSS stylesheet use the relative unit (%) for `width` property; second, for font-size property use either `pt` or `em` units; third, set `overflow` and `white-space` properties, like for e.g.: `overflow-y:scroll`, `overflow-x:hidden`, `white-space: nowrap`, etc.
Hope this may help.